# Change android apk version with appcelerator

Tags: android, titanium, apk, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

when i try to update my alpha release i receive the error that i need to change my apk version. But how can i do that? my android manifest:

```
<android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionName="1.1">
        <manifest>
            <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="23"/>
            <application>
                <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"
                    android:name="org.appcelerator.titanium.TiActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
                <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden" android:name="ti.modules.titanium.ui.TiTabActivity"/>
            </application>
        </manifest>
    </android>
```

Comment: What error did you receive exactly? The `targetSdkVerison` is the one you compile against, the other is the minimum.

Comment: ALso, what TiSDK do you use?

Comment: i use the last sdk 5.1.2 GA. The problem isn't sdks version, but apk version. This is the error when i try upload the new version on google play:

Upload failed You need to use a different version code for your APK because you already have one with version code 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah, you talk about APK version, not about Android SDK. The solution is simple. You need to change the version at a couple places.

Change the version tag with at least the 3rd number (patch) increased

`<version>1.0</version>`

Can become

`<version>1.0.1</version>` or `<version>1.1</version>`

Next, you also need to change the part in the android manifest

```
    <manifest android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0.1" package="com.example.app"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
```

Increase version code every time, can be same as version, in my example `101` for example. Or just a build number (1, 2, 3, etc)

Versionname should be the same as the version in the version tag. Also don't forget to put your app ID in the same code ;)

Comment: My issue was i added that property to my <android>. Thank you!

Comment: Setting `android:versionName` will override `<version>`. So you do not need to set both unless you also target iOS and do not set an iOS specific version as well.

Answer (score 1):

In TiApp.xml add version code and version name to manifest

```
<manifest android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
```

Google is mainly complaining about version code so check that and increase by one. These settings will override the version of the app specified in the  tag for android

Answer (score 0):

Each APK you submit to Google Play must have a unique, incremental build version, which on Android is `android:versionCode`.

Titanium will use the `<version>` tag in `tiapp.xml` to set the release version which on Android is `android:versionName`.

To set the build version you need to add/use a `<manifest>` element under the `<android>` element in `tiapp.xml` like this:

```
<android>
  <manifest android:versionCode="1">
  ..
  </manifest>
</android>
```

The [4.1.0 Sample](https://github.com/appcelerator-developer-relations/appc-sample-ti410) included a [Gruntfile.js](https://github.com/appcelerator-developer-relations/appc-sample-ti410/blob/master/Gruntfile.js) to easily increment the iOS and Android build versions. It can even bump the major, minor or patch release version for you.

Please read the [blog post](http://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2015/07/versioning-your-apps-with-4-1-0/) on versioning your apps with Titanium 4.1.0 and later for more information.

Answer (score -1):

you also have to increment

`<version>1.1</version>`

Comment: and you also incremented android:versionName?

Comment: You do not need to increment the `<version>` tag if you already have set the `android:versionName` as it overrides that for Android.